# bundling in mvc to load new set of files for every release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

**I need to bundle my .js files and lib files in my Mvc project, i am looking for version number for bundle, as my browser need to reload all .js and .lib files when ever new version is added or build is pushed to dev/testing/prod environments.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling in ASP.NET MVC already has a built-in mechanism for handling these type of cache-busting scenarios for release builds as [per the "Bundle Caching" section of this documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) :

> As long as the bundle doesn't change, the ASP.NET application will request the AllMyScripts  bundle using this token. If any file in the
>   bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework will generate a new
>   token, guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the
>   latest bundle.

This features uses a token within the querystring called `v` to indicate current "version" of the bundle that looks like :

```
v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81
```

This functions as a unique identifier for the particular build and as long as nothing in the bundle was changed, it will continue to use it, otherwise a new one would be generated to "bust" any existing caching.

**For Non-Release Builds**

If you needed to handle this in non-release builds, then I believe you could set the `EnableOptimizations` property to `true` to always handle this :

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: **It Worked**, thanks for your reply now i could see different tokens when .js files are updated.